# angucomplete-alt unable to type in textbox

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Simple problem here - but cant seem to find answer. I have added the angucomplete-alt to my project - I believe that I have added it all correctly - meaning, registering it and having the js file available when the page loads. But for some reason when I click on the input and start to type - nothing happens. I am unable to type in the textbox/input. below is my code for the control. - im double checking how things are wired up on the back end. - thanks in advance.

and this exact code works in another project - configured differently - but the markup for the control is the same

```
<angucomplete-alt id="searchGroupsAutoComplete"
                                          placeholder="{{searchPlaceholder}}"
                                          pause="400"
                                          text-searching="{{searchingText}}"
                                          selected-object="selectedAnObjectFn"
                                          remote-url="/api/search/SearchByQueryStrings"
                                          remote-url-request-formatter="formatSearchDataFn"
                                          remote-url-response-formatter="formatReturnDataFn"
                                          remote-url-data-field="Content"
                                          title-field="Name"
                                          description-field="EntityType"
                                          image-field="ThumbnailUrl"
                                          minlength="1" />
```

Comment: I dont have a solution for this - but on this page I am also using ng-nestable - and that isnt working great either (trying to remove items from the list with a button - doesnt like / or allow the ng-click) but if i take this out. the ng-model="mdl" and put in an ng-repeat="item in mdl" - then that textbox in my angucomplete works - but you have to have ng-model next to the ng-nestable so ng-repeat wont work

Comment: almost like - (possibly is) being set as disable?

Answer (score 1):

```
Remove maxlength="{{maxlength}}" of INPUT tag in $templateCache.put(TEMPLATE_URL,..... (angucomplete-alt.js)
```

so it worked, but I don't known why.