# Angular - ng-nestable remove item

Tags: angularjs

I have added the ng-nestable feature to our project. I have added a button to this section of code - I am trying to wire up this button to remove items from the collection/json - It does not like or allow an ng-click - when you click in one of these sections it is thinking Im re-ordering the selection. I need to have the ability to remove items from my list.

```
<div ng-nestable ng-model="mdl">
                            <div class="board-master__contentItem">
                                <div class="board-master__contentItemLeft">
                                    {{item.text}}
                                </div>
                                <div class="board-master__contentItemRight">
                                    <div class="btn-warning btn board-master__footerButton" ng-click="RemoveFromBoard($item)">Remove</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try hooking up a `ng-mousedown` on the element where you have `ng-click` and invoke the `stopPropagation` method on the mousedown event there

Comment: if you can help me with this one Id wind up with a good finish to the day. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30672962/angucomplete-alt-unable-to-type-in-textbox